# Move Files of certain extension types From a User Selected Folder To a New Folder

Tags: vb.net

Using a button, I am attempting to allow a user to select a folder they wish to moves files from of only the following extensions: .shp, .dbf and .shx, to a folder that will be created upon moving these files with a set name (i.e. Exports).

EDIT*

Ok, here is what I have come up with:

```
Private Sub SelectFolder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectFolder.Click
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            lstFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal folderPath As String)
        lstFiles.Items.Clear()

        Dim fileNames = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
            folderPath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.shp", "*.shx", "*.dbf")

        For Each fileName As String In fileNames
            lstfiles.Items.Add(fileName)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Am I thinking about it this in the correct way?

Comment: Congratulations. Let us know if you encounter an actual issue in doing so.

Comment: Any code to review it with you?

Comment: Ok, I have edited my post with the code I currently have together adding the required file types to a listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some tips:

To get specific file types from a directory, you can do:

```vb
Imports System.IO

'...

Dim tar = {".shp", ".shx", ".dbf"}
Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
    Where(Function(x) tar.Contains(Path.GetExtension(x).ToLower)).
    Select(Function(x) New FileInfo(x))
```

Or by using the [RegExp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions):

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

'...

Dim pattern = "^.*?(\.dbf|\.shp|\.shx)$"
Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
    Where(Function(x) Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).
    Select(Function(x) New FileInfo(x))
```

To show the `files` in a `ListBox`:

```vb
lstFiles.DataSource = Nothing
'Or FullName to display the path.
lstFiles.DisplayMember = "Name"
lstFiles.DataSource = files.ToList
```

Now to copy these files to another folder and append a prefix/postfix:

```vb
Dim files = DirectCast(lstFiles.DataSource, List(Of FileInfo))
Dim dest As String = "DestinationPath"
Dim postfix As String = "Exports"

If Not Directory.Exists(dest) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dest)
End If

files.ForEach(Sub(x)
                  x.CopyTo(Path.Combine(dest,
                           $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name)}_{postfix}{x.Extension}"),
                  True)
              End Sub)
```

That's it all.

Comment: Thank you, this all works seamlessly. An additional question, and I may be misunderstanding, but how do I define the "Destination Path" for these files to move to? Is this the best means? `Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RbtnBrowse.Click
  FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = "C:\"
  FolderBrowserDialog1.Description = "Select A Destination Folder"

  If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
   txtPath.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
  End If
 End Sub`

Comment: Yes. Use this way if you want to allow the user to specify the destination. Otherwise just hard code it. i.e. `dest = "c:\MyTmpFolder"`