# Iterate over a directory and filter results based on file extensions

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function that cycles through a directory and, for each folder within that directory, returns the most recent file. The problem is that the folders contain files of different formats, such as `.xlsx` and `.csv`. The file extensions may change per request, so I need to pass them as a parameter to the function, instead of hard-coding the values. How can I pass a list of file extensions as a parameter and select the file according to its extension? Here's what I'm trying to do:

```cs
  var extensions = new string[] { ".xlsx", ".csv" };
  var filename = FileSystemService.GetRecentFile(path,  extensions.ToList<string>);
```

Comment: Do you need the most recent file for each extension in the array or just one file having one of the extensions declared?

Comment: Hey Costa, can you provide the code for your `GetRecentFile()` method? That's likely going to be needed to provide a meaningful answer that works with your approach.

Comment: Does the most recent file have to be of one of the types, or can it be of any type at all as long as it is most recent?

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. Are you asking how to *pass* the file extensions (and if so, what is wrong with what you have?) OR are you asking how to modify the method to *accept* them (in which case where is the code?)

Comment: Hello guys, sorry for the delay. The FileSystemService class traverses a directory structure. According to an option made by the user, he will access one of these directories. The question is: in each of these directories, files of type .xlsx or .csv are stored, so I need a function that checks which extension the GetRecentFile function will search for the most recent file for. Am I clear?

Comment: If you don't mind vb.net code, then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59995641/move-files-of-certain-extension-types-from-a-user-selected-folder-to-a-new-folde/60008158#60008158).

Comment: @JQSOFT, this work in c#?

Comment: Yes if you convert it to c#. Anyways you have two beautiful answers already.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the most recent file having one of the extensions required, then this could be a solution:

```
public FileInfo GetRecent(string path, params string[] extensions)
{
    var list = new List<FileInfo>();

    // Getting all files having required extensions
    // Note that extension is case insensitive with this code
    foreach (var ext in extensions)
        list.AddRange(
          new DirectoryInfo(path)
            .EnumerateFiles("*" + ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(p =>
              p.Extension.Equals(ext,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
              .ToArray());

    return list.Any()
        // If list has somm file then return the newest one
        ? list.OrderByDescending(i => i.LastWriteTime)
              .FirstOrDefault()
        // else return what you please, it could be null
        : null;
}
```

---

If you need the most recent file for each extension, then this could be a solution:

```
public Dictionary<string, FileInfo> GetRecents(string path, params string[] extensions)
{
    var ret = new Dictionary<string, FileInfo>();

    // Getting all files having required extensions
    // Note that extension is case insensitive with this code
    foreach (var ext in extensions)
    {
        var files = new DirectoryInfo(path)
            .EnumerateFiles("*" + ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(p =>
                p.Extension.Equals(ext, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .ToArray();

        ret.Add(ext, files.Any()
        ? files.OrderByDescending(i => i.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault()
        : null);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return` the result of the `FirstOrDefault` call, since that already returns `null` if there are no matches?

Comment: @RufusL: yes you're absolutely right, but I left that just in case OP wanted to return something different.

Answer (score 2):

You could first enumerate the Sub-Directories in the provided path, using [Directory.EnumerateDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories). This enumeration excludes the root, so we can add it back to the Enumerable, if required, using the [Prepend()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend)<sup>1</sup> or [Append()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append)<sup>1</sup> methods.

Then iterate the collection of extensions, call [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles) to get Date/Time information about the files in each Directory and filter using the **`FileInfo.LastWriteTime`** value and finally order by the most recent and **`yield return`** the first result.

I've used a public methods that calls a private worker method, so the public method can be used to provide some more filters or it could be more easily overloaded. Here it's used to provide an option to return the most recent file of all.

It can be called as:

```
string[] extensions = { ".png", ".jpg", "*.txt" };
var mostRecentFiles = GetMostRecentFilesByExtension(@"[RootPath]", extensions, false);
```

Specify **`false`** to get all the files by type and directory, or **`true`** to get the most recent file among all files that matched the criteria.

```
public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetMostRecentFilesByExtension(string path, IEnumerable<string> extensions, bool returnSingle)
{
    var mostRecent = MostRecentFileByExtension(path, extensions).Where(fi => fi != null);
    if (returnSingle) {
        return mostRecent.OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastWriteTime).Take(1);
    }
    else {
        return mostRecent;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<FileInfo> MostRecentFileByExtension(string path, IEnumerable<string> exts)
{
    foreach (string dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Prepend(path))
    foreach (string ext in exts) {
        yield return new DirectoryInfo(dir)
                        .EnumerateFiles($"*{ext}")
                        .Where(fi => fi.Extension.Equals(ext, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        .OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

> <sup>(1) Both `Prepend()` and `Append()` require .Net Framework 4.7.1.
>   Core/Standard Frameworks all have them.</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you search _"*.msi"_ then you get also files like _file1.msis_. I don't know if this behaviour changed in the last frameworks, but in the past it worked like that. So if you didn't compare extension and just use GetFiles, then you ended having unneeded files!

Comment: I confirm that if you search _"*.msi"_ then you get also files like _file1.msis_ even with last framework!

Comment: @Marco That's a minor thing. I've added a filter, in case it's needed. It's also one of those possible *filters and/or overloads* I was referring to. The *specs* don't specify whether the extension match should be considered case sensitive either. The OP can modify the behavior with as option to consider the `CurrentCulture/CurrentUICulture` instead of `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Comment: @Marco Well, *perfect*... I wish I had *perfection* on my side :) Thanks, anyway. I see your answer has a downvote, but it looks like it's working, so +1. The answers are slightly different, good for the OP.

Comment: Well, I don't know the reason of the downvote (I wish I could know so I could amend my answer), but I know my code works... never mind, we're here to help and receive help not to get points ;)